# Converting to Storyboards , rootviewcontroller problems

Tags: objective-c

This is the error I'm getting: "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

From what I've read i need to pass the delegate to the view controller using rootviewcontroller but Obviously i did something wrong.

I added a new storyboard to my project and changed it to main in the summery.
 this is my Appdelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    menu.delegate = self;
    [self.window addSubview:menu];
    [menu release];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: What is menu? You haven't done anything in this code to instantiate your storyboard. In the info screen do you have an entry that's called "Main storyboard file base name" whose value is the name of your storyboard? I have no idea what you mean by "i need to pass the delegate to the view controller using rootviewcontroller". That has nothing to do with getting your root view controller to show up. You should have a view controller in your storyboard that has an arrow coming in from the left (not connected to anything else).

Comment: I got a storyboard with an arrow. How do i get the main window of my working app to show up inside my view controller?

Comment: I also have the entry in the info plist, my problem is to see the main screen inside my view controller. for now i removed the line `self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];` from Appdelegate.m and searching with what to replace it with.

Comment: If your app is set up correctly, you shouldn't need any code other than return YES; in you app delegate. Having the entry in the plist file, and a contoller that has the "is initial view contoller" check box checked in IB should be enough for it to work.

Comment: ^ You are right, there was something wrong in the code. It's working fine now. I do have a followup question regarding this matter. Posted it a few hours ago. (You can edit your comment to an answer so i can mark it as solved.)